# How I can removie html extensions

Tags: url, html, web-development, css3

I'm new at web development, I have a question, Thank you all for your answers.

I made a website with HTML5 and CSS, I Published my website on my website host using FTP (FileZilla Client), But when I open my pages, I mean when I open About page Or home page of my website the url is:
www.mywebsite.com/index.html
www.mywebsite.com/about.html

Now I want to remove That html extensions from all pages of my website.
What is the simple  methods and solution?

Thank you all!

.